# Parsing a delimited text file in bash as command arguments

Tags: bash, text-processing, scripting, csv

I have a text file split up like so:

```
field1,field2,field3 
xield1,xield2,xield3 
dield1,dield2,dield3 
gield1,gield2,gield3
```

Each of these columns will be a parameter to a program, and I would like the program to be called for each line

I was hoping for a loop, something like:

```
for $i in file
    command $field2 -x $field3 -PN -$field1 >> output
done
```

What would be the best way to accomplish something like this in bash?

Comment: Is the number of fields constant?

Comment: @JosephR. yes they are, always 3

Answer (score 8):

```
while IFS=, read xx yy zz;do
    echo $xx $yy $zz
done < input_file
```

This should work if the number of fields are constant.
Instead of `echo` use your command.

Comment: Thanks, I was just trying this but it only seems to work for the first line. As soon as a command succeeds it doesn't try the next one, if it fails it will try the next one though...

Comment: How do you mean by success or fail? What your command does?

Comment: I would guess that the command he is running is reading standard input before the "read" comand can get at it.

Answer (score 5):

You should use a `while` with the `read` built-in:

```
while IFS= read -r line;do
    fields=($(printf "%s" "$line"|cut -d',' --output-delimiter=' ' -f1-))
    command "${fields[1]}" -x "${fields[2]}" ... # ${fields[1]} is field 2
done < your_file_here
```

**How this works**

- The `cut` statement takes the line and splits it on the delimiter specified by `-d`.
- The `--output-delimiter` is the separator character that `cut` will use to display the selected fields, here we choose a space so we can put the different fields into the array `fields`.
- Finally, we want all fields (from field 1 to the end) and that's where `-f1-` comes into play.
- Now you have the different fields stored in the array variable `fields`, you can access any particular field you want with the syntax `${field[number]}` where `number` is one less than the actual field number you want since array indexing is zero-based in Bash.

**Note**

- This will fail if any of your fields contains whitespace.

**For a constant number of fields**

You can instead do something similar to [1_CR's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/103937/26909):

```
while IFS= read -r line;do
    IFS=, read -r field1 field2 field3 <<-EOI
    $line
    EOI
    command "$field2" -x "$field3" ... 
done < your_file_here
```

The above, while seeming more noisy, should work in any POSIX-compliant shell, not just Bash.

Comment: It's not reading in the file that I have trouble with, it's breaking up the line into columns.

Comment: @Dean Yeah, sorry. I wasn't paying attention. Working on that now.

Comment: @Dean Please see the updated answer. I will add an explanation shortly.

Comment: @JosephR., it's possible to avoid using external tools for the splitting by setting `IFS` to an appropriate value in the `read` invocation

Comment: @1_CR I know, thanks. I was just getting to that :)

Answer (score 1):

You can get `read` to split each line into an array on `,` by setting `IFS` appropriately.

```
while IFS=, read -r -a input; do
 printf "%s\n" "${input[0]}" "${input[1]}"
done < input.txt
```

So in the example above, you may access each array element using its index, starting 0.

Answer (score 1):

This `awk` one-liner will do what you want:

```
awk -F, '{cmd="echo " $2 " -x " $3 " -PN " $1 ">> output";  system(cmd)}' f.txt
```

Replace `echo` with your command and `f.txt` with the file that you wish to iterate through.

Brief explanation: `-F,` will set `,` as the delimiter. `cmd` builds the command and `system(cmd)` calls the command.

Answer (score 1):

gnu sed can be used as well.

```
sed infile -e 's!^\([^,]*\),\([^,]*\),\([^,]*\)$!command \1 -x \2 -PN \3!e' >> output
```

notice the use of the e option to the s command