# Setting a IFS for a bash script

Tags: bash, environment-variables, read

The typical case is `IFS= read`.
The subject is very well explained in this thread:
[why is setting a variable before a command legal in bash?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/126938/why-is-setting-a-variable-before-a-command-legal-in-bash)
In order to have a complete picture, I'd be very grateful if you guys could explain why the following script doesn't work as (I) expected.
`my_script`:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "$var1"
echo -n "$IFS" | xxd -p
echo "$var2"

exit 0
```

calling `my_script`:

```
var1=foo IFS= var2=bar my_script
```

output:

```
foo
20090a
bar
```

As you can see `IFS` is unchanged, still set as default.
How does `read` get the custom `IFS` when called as `IFS= read`?
Thank you in advance

Comment: See also [When can I use a temporary IFS for field splitting?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/264635/when-can-i-use-a-temporary-ifs-for-field-splitting/264642#264642) (but, as Thomas Dickey's answer explains, you aren't getting that far).

Answer (score 12):

The example does not set `IFS` within the script, because bash disallows importing `IFS` from the environment, according to a comment in [`variables.c`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/variables.c#n500):

```c
  /* Don't allow IFS to be imported from the environment. */
  temp_var = bind_variable ("IFS", " \t\n", 0);
  setifs (temp_var);
```

Built-in commands and non-*script* uses get the assignment to `IFS`, of course, but keep in mind that `IFS` only applies to [word-splitting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-word-splitting):

> The shell treats each character of `$IFS` as a delimiter, and splits the results of the other expansions into words using these characters as field terminators. If `IFS` is unset, or its value is exactly `<space><tab><newline>`, the default, then sequences of `<space>`, `<tab>`, and `<newline>` at the beginning and end of the results of the previous expansions are ignored, and any sequence of `IFS` characters not at the beginning or end serves to delimit words. If `IFS` has a value other than the default, then sequences of the whitespace characters space and tab are ignored at the beginning and end of the word, as long as the whitespace character is in the value of `IFS` (an `IFS` whitespace character). Any character in `IFS` that is not IFS whitespace, along with any adjacent `IFS` whitespace characters, delimits a field. A sequence of `IFS` whitespace characters is also treated as a delimiter. If the value of `IFS` is null, no word splitting occurs.