# Environment and systemd

Tags: linux, systemd, drivers, audio

All what I'm trying to do is to get VOL variable from /sound.cfg, depended by DEV number.

```
cat /sound.cfg
VOL1=20%
```

Systemd startup script includes:

```
[Service]
Environment="DEV=1"
EnvironmentFile=/sound.cfg
ExecStartPre=-/bin/bash -c "VOL=VOL${DEV} /bin/echo /usr/bin/amixer -c chan.${DEV} sset Mic ${!VOL} dev $DEV"
```

Unfortunately, echo shows me `/usr/bin/amixer -c chan.1 sset Mic dev 1`, without needed `VOL1`. Systemd doesn't support arrays, which would be very helpful.

Comment: You can't set a variable and use it in the same line. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/126947/70524

Comment: You have right. I've changed a few lines, but it doens't work also

`[Service]
Environment="DEV=1"
EnvironmentFile=/sound.cfg
Environment="VOL=VOL${DEV}"
ExecStartPre=-/bin/echo /usr/bin/amixer -c chan.${DEV} sset Mic ${!VOL} dev $DEV`

Still no VOL1 value.

Comment: Try `ExecStartPre=-/bin/bash -c 'VOL=VOL$1 DEV=$2; /bin/echo /usr/bin/amixer -c chan.$DEV sset Mic ${!VOL} dev $DEV' _ ${VOL} ${DEV}`. But you might better off putting the commands in a script.

Comment: I tried, but without success. As you suggested - I've made an extra script which works as expected. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Since you want the shell to expand that variable, not systemd, use `$${!VOL}` ...

Comment: PS: put a semi colon after the setting of the variable e.g. `VOL=VOL${DEV}; /bin/echo ...` to avoid the problem mentioned by @muru