# Cut Reorder and Output to Text

Tags: shell-script, centos, text-processing, cut

I'm currently learning CentOS and need some assistance if possible. I have a file UserNameList.lst, which is used to generate user accounts. The content of the file is below

```
Josh, Adams, Joshadams@gmail.com
Henry, Ford, HFord@gmail.com
```

I need to output a txt file which looks like this. (basically combining column 2 and 1 to make a single column)

```
Adams Josh
Ford Henry
```

I tried using the command

```
cut -d "," -f 1 >> Last.txt
cut -d "," -f 2 >> First.txt
paste First.txt Last.txt >> full
```

which outputs

```
Adams    Josh
Ford     Henry
```

Is there a simpler way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is best suited for `awk`

```
$ cat ip.txt 
Josh, Adams, Joshadams@gmail.com
Henry, Ford, HFord@gmail.com

$ awk -F"[ ,]+" '{print $2, $1}' ip.txt 
Adams Josh
Ford Henry
```

- `-F"[ ,]+"` field separator is one or more of space and `,` characters
- Then simply print second and first columns

Comment: thanks for the prompt reply! Would you happen to know if I would be able to assign each column to a variable to use as a variable for loop?

Comment: @Leon, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/103932/parsing-a-delimited-text-file-in-bash-as-command-arguments